# python pass extra information through nested for/in/if loop that iterates over items in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, python-asyncio

The basics of my issue is passing along "extra" information while I'm iterating over a data frame. I am passing each value in the dataframe to a function to be checked. But I need to pass and return some extra identifying information as well. (The ID number.) So I need a way that allows me to pass this extra info to the next function so that I can return it with the result of that function.

Basic problem:

```
import pandas as pd

urls = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

for col in urls.columns:
    for url in urls[col]:
        if url:
            print(url,col)
#I need to be able to print the corresponding ID that belongs to each URL
```

Desired output:

```
ID    URL     COL
1     apple   link1
etc...
```

I think if that can be done with the for/in/if structure, then it can be applied to the real code below:

---

The real code is a little more complex. I am using asyncio.gather to process the dataframe. Passing the column name was simple, but I don't know how to get the ID.

```
import asyncio, aiohttp, time, pandas as pd
from validator_collection import checkers

url_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

async def get(url, sem, session,col):
    try:
            async with sem, session.get(url=url,raise_for_status=True, timeout=20) as response:
                    resp = await response.read()
                    print("Successfully got url {} from column {} with response of length {}.".format(url, col, len(resp)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))


async def main(urls):
    sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(50)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get(url, sem, session, col) 
                                                for col in urls.columns #for each column in the dataframe
                                                    for url in urls[col] #for each row in the column
                                                        if url #if the item isn't null
                                                            if checkers.is_url(url)==True]) #if url is valid
    print("Finalized all. ret is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(ret)))

amount = url_df.count(axis='columns').sum()
start = time.time()
asyncio.run(main(url_df))
end = time.time()

print("Took {} seconds to pull {} websites.".format(end - start, amount))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterating over all columns, it sounds like it might make sense (?) if you want to iterate over the rows instead.

There are many ways you could go about this:

For starters, it might make sense to index your dataframe by the ID column:

```py
url_df = url_df.set_index('ID')
```

Then, among other possibilities, you could use the `itertuples()` method:

```
for row in url_df.itertuples():
    # The first item will always be the index, so:
    ID = row[0]  # or ID = row.Index
    
    # Then do whatever you want for the other columns:
    for link in row[1:]:
        print(ID, link)
```

Output:

```
1 apple
1 http://www.bing.com
1 http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com
2 www.google.com
2 http://www.linkedin.com
2 http://www.imdb.com
5 gm@yahoo.com
5 
5 http://www.google.co.uk
25 http://www.youtube.com
25  please call now
25 more random text that could be really long and annoying
26 888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io
26 http://www.reddit.com
26 over the hills and through the woods
```

If you want to include the column names as well you could do it like:

```
for row in url_df.itertuples():
    # The first item will always be the index, so:
    ID = row[0]  # or ID = row.Index
    
    # Then do whatever you want for the other columns:
    for link, col in zip(row[1:], row._fields[1:]):
        print(ID, link, col)
```

For use in your actual code, it might be clearer if you wrapped this up in a subroutine like:

```
def iter_links(df):
    for row in url_df.itertuples():
        # The first item will always be the index, so:
        ID = row[0]  # or ID = row.Index
    
        # Then do whatever you want for the other columns:
        for url, col in zip(row[1:], row._fields[1:]):
            if url and checkers.is_url(url):
                yield (ID, col, url)
```

Then use this in your code like:

```
await asyncio.gather(*(get(sess, sem, ID, col, url)
                       for ID, col, url in iter_links(df)))
```

Comment: I was actually starting to think about trying iterrows and see where that got me.  The tricky part to a multipart solution (at least for me) is applying it to the actual code with the asyncio.gather. (The bottom of my post.)  I'll give this a shot and report back!

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this result in the problem then becoming how to bring the column name through instead?  The end goal is to know which row and column a link comes from.

Comment: I updated the answer to give some ideas how to go about simplifying your code.

Comment: *googles python zip function*  Thanks! I'll give this a shot and report back.  (Not sure if it matters, but for general information, the dataframe is 15 or so columns wide, and 300k rows tall. - if that would cause you to think of a different implementation.)

Comment: Did you mean to make the ```# The first item will always be the index, so:
    ID = row[0]  # or ID = row.Index``` be ```ID = row[1]``` instead?  That way it uses the ID number instead of the index number?

Comment: That would depend on whether or not you set ID to be the index of the DataFrame as I wrote in the beginning of my answer `url_df = url_df.set_index('ID')`.  I think this is practical to do since it makes the ID column "special" in a way, and guaranteed to be the first tuple element regardless of how the other columns are ordered.

Comment: Ohhh, I missed putting that piece back into the mix. Got it!  Thank you!!!!  For my next hurdle, and possibly a new question... I think I can use iter_links function and create additional tuples that deal with fields that have delimited links.

Comment: @Steve Yes, you could definitely do that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236148/discussion-between-steve-and-iguananaut).

Answer (score 1):

If you can clean up the urls string so you can split them the below could work better (like a loop doing `for link in s.split('|'):` or split on `;` etc.  All depends on what data cleaning and wrangling you can do beforehand though.

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

def getDomain(s):
    if bool(urlparse(s).scheme):
        return urlparse(s).netloc

for row in urls.itertuples():
    print(row[1], getDomain(row[2]), getDomain(row[3]), getDomain(row[4]))
    print('\n')

1 None www.bing.com www.stackoverflow.com~|~http:

2 None www.linkedin.com www.imdb.com

5 None None www.google.co.uk

25 www.youtube.com None None

26 None www.reddit.com None
```

---

**Additional:**

To clean up the URL columns you may want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re
import numpy as np

urls = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

startURL = re.compile(r'(?:www|http://www)')
sURL = re.compile(r'((?:www\.|https?://www\.|https?://).*?\.(?:$|[A-Za-z0-9.]+))')

def extractDomain(s):
    pos = []
    l = []
    for m in startURL.finditer(s):
        pos.append(m.start())
    for p in pos:
        n = urlparse(sURL.search(s[p:]).group(1)).netloc
        if n == '':
            l.append(urlparse(sURL.search(s[p:]).group(1)).path)
        else:
            l.append(urlparse(sURL.search(s[p:]).group(1)).netloc)
    if len(l) > 0:
        #return ', '.join(l) #return a string
        return l # return a list

filter_col = [col for col in urls if col.startswith('link')]

df_links = urls[filter_col].copy()

df_links.columns = [str(col) + '_clean' for col in df_links.columns]

df_links = df_links.applymap(extractDomain)

urls = urls.join(df_links)

# example of link3 column change
print(urls[['ID', 'link3', 'link3_clean']])

    ID  link3                                               link3_clean
0   1   http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay...   [www.stackoverflow.com, www.ebay.com]
1   2   http://www.imdb.com                                 [www.imdb.com]
2   5   http://www.google.co.uk                             [www.google.co.uk]
3   25  more random text that could be really long and...   None
4   26  over the hills and through the woods                None
```

Comment: I think this might be more applicable to my NEXT project/question. Which is how to handle the delimited data.  in the link3 column for item ID1, you can see two url's delimited by ~|~. I have to figure out how to break those apart, yet still keep track of them to report back after checking if they are still active.

Comment: @Steve i updated the code with an idea for getting the URLs cleaned up.  It may be useful for the next part :o)